# Eclipse vs Netbeans Benchmark

Tags: eclipse, performance, netbeans, ide

Is there any benchmarks or study done comparing these two IDEs in terms of

-- stability
-- developer productivity
-- features
-- performance
-- etc.

Comment: It's worth noting that currently NetBeans only supports Java 9 through its nightly development builds (http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/). Those builds work fine for me, but that may be a consideration if you need a stable and proven environment for Java 9 development.

Answer (score 1):

I am an Eclipse user (not by choice). Not sure about stability, but performance wise NetBeans is far supperior at least with the lates versions that I worked in; personally, I think NetBeans has enough features to make it a good development environment but I can't tell you for sure, it depends on what is the scope of your task. Overall, eclipse is a good IDE, but NetBeans is just a little better...

Answer (score 1):

Mostly working with eclipse nowadays.

All I can say is M2E is a pain.
With no disrespect intended to the developers of m2e ...
This is the simply the absolute worst plugin for maven. It is slow and it is painful to use.
For big maven projects with more than 70 module components, you can forget about having a quick eclipse evironment.

If you use mvn eclipse:eclipse, the deprecated plugin for configuring eclipse, I believe you are faster with eclipse than with netbeans. Especially when it comes to refactoring.

If instead you use the official m2e plugin ...
Oh my god!

I am answering to this question due to the pure shear pain of waiting for eclipse.
" Invoking CDI Builder" because an @Inject collaborator moved around in the class, triggering a massive build wait time delay... god!

Eclipse! Well... Eclipse is a great IDE for getting started, on small projects, but as projects get enterprise level, and if you use m2e ... oh! you will cry!
And wonder ... how can it be this bad.

Netbeans! Perhaps nota any better in the end.
Last time I used Netbeans, i had two major complaints, that were total deal brekers:
(a) Netbeans was simply awful when dealing with massiven class refactoring.
You change  a class name on sub module A, that affects modules B, C and D.
And until you class renaming, move over packages is done, you can go take a coffee, and order a cab.

(b) netbeans had a bug in parsing interfaces, namely there was some sort of regular expression that would take the longest time to run.
So if you can use the old deprecated mvn eclipse:eclipse, you would end up being far better of.

With that said.
The Netbeans debugger compared to the eclipse debugger is light years better.
I prefer the graphics of netbeans and I prefer the simplicity of netbeans.
Just try using the "expressions" where the autocomplete does not work, and you ave to go to "display" to get autcomplete to work and copy it bakc over to expressions! 
Eclipse is a patch work, with hundreds of thousands of developers making hundreds of different components of the IDE, leading to an overall result of a total inconsistent product.

Eclipse is a never ending set of settings, just open the preferences and ...

Netbeans, UI is always desing for maximum simplicty.

As I wait for my m2e to finish rebuilding prjects based on whatever whim lead eclipse to start a new build, I start considering again if I should not revisit Netbeans and install the eclipse formatter ...

Eclipse is really in bad shape, In my humble oppinion.
Ther performance of eclipse has to improve 100 fold, especiall eclipse + m2e has to get way way better.
Intelli J - i have never tried.

The best IDE  have used so far, is wihout any doubt, Microsfot Visual Code for Javascript and TypeScript.

You use Microsoft Visual Code, and just wonder why eclipse is not like that.
If you are doing Angular Js/Typecipt, simply forget about any other IDE out there. Microsoft Visual Code is the best thing there is, it is fantastic and joy to use.
Blazing fast and light and good looking on every platform of your desire.

But for java + maven, the echo system is a bit lacking on good options.
The man is not supposed to wait for the machine.
A human is always supposed to be slower then a machine ... this is not the case with eclipse m2e, this I can tell you.
The furstration!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have lots of hardware to throw at it, go with Netbeans.

I have a VM running CentOS 7. At this time, I am only able to allocate 2G ram to the VM, and running Eclipse Oxygen for PHP on it is **painfully slow**. Netbeans runs just fine in this configuration.

I'm sure some Eclipse devotee would suggest giving the VM more ram which might probably resolve the issue, but unfortunately that is not currently possible.

Another thing that ought to be mentioned is that Eclipse is rather unique in its UI. For example, virtually every editor on the planet uses Ctrl-F to "**F**ind", then function key **F3** to "Find Next". Ctrl-G is "**G**oto line number". Netbeans follows this convention. Eclipse, however, uses Ctrl-K to "Find Next" and Ctrl-L for "**L**ine number".

This won't be an issue if you use Eclipse and nothing else, but if you're like the more typical developer, you use Eclipse when appropriate along with some other tool when appropriate. You **will** get confused sometimes and use the wrong shortcut. This creates unpredictable problems, particularly if you're unsure what the wrong shortcut just did to your file.

It's not a "performance" issue as per the application, but it **slows down the developer**. To me, that's just as bad.

Again, some Eclipse devotee might suggest that Eclipse shortcuts can be configured any way you like, which is true, but *really*, does anybody have that kind of time? Eclipse comes with literally *thousands* of configuration options, and it's an Internet Search to figure out how to change almost anything.

Netbeans doesn't have thousands of configuration options, although there are things you can tweak. It just sorta mostly works the way you expect out of the box.

To conclude, the actual slowness on less-than-most-super-powerful hardware is probably the biggest thing against Eclipse. I don't know what the code is trying to do, but Netbeans is somehow able to do it with less hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and Netbeans are both good IDE (Integrated Development Environment) programs. If you are just a Java, C++, C or Fortran programmer you can use any of them. 
If you are WEB base developer (For Example: JSF, Serverlet, Applet) in this case NetBeans is much more powerful then Eclipse.
On the other hand, If you are mobile developer for Android OS, in this case Eclipse is much more powerful then Netbeans.
So it depends on your programming league :)))